# How to use NewRelic to monitor Rails exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

Is it possible to use NewRelic to monitor exceptions in Rails app (like Airbrake)

Bonus: Get notified of other custom errors (e.g. Users getting form validation errors)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Relic does indeed track exceptions, with a free subscription. It will also let you call an [API to report custom errors](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration).

Comment: I assume I am not the first to need this. Any gems/libs/snippets that implement this connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Zapier provides a connector to New Relic, that in theory would allow you to send emails when a new relic alert occurs.

Haven't tested myself but it probably let you use New Relic as airbrake.

Here is the link: https://zapier.com/app/explore